# Is PGM (Pragmatic General Multicast) viable to achieve reliable message delivery with IP multicast?

Tags: networks

I have a server application that distributes stock quotes to a number of clients on our internal network. As the number of clients has grown, unicast (TCP) connections between the server and the clients do not scale anymore. Hence, I have been looking into multicasts.

Because of the inherent unreliability of IP multicast, I have been looking into reliable multicast and found [Pragmatic General Multicast (PGM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_General_Multicast). Things like NAK suppression, forward error correction etc. sound like just the things I need and would have to implement myself when using raw UDP.

Before I convert a mission critical application to this protocol, there are a couple of questions:

- **How widely used is PGM?** There aren’t many hits for it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pgm%20multicast), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=pgm) or the new [Network Engineering Stack Exchange site](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=pgm). The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3208)  is from 2001 and a [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=68888) on the Microsoft Research site is from 2003. Why hasn’t this been adopted as a standard already?
- **How viable is the Microsoft implementation of PGM?** The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740125%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is extremely sparse and most projects using PGM (e.g. [zeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/)) seem to be built on top of [OpenPGM](http://code.google.com/p/openpgm/). But using a socket API that comes with the operating system and that I am already familiar and that has good support in Delphi and C# (the languages I use) seems better than having to rely on additional libraries that need to be built separately and have their own dependencies. Are there any drawbacks of MS-PGM that I should be aware of?
- **What are the alternatives?** Are there other protocols that bring reliability to multicast programming, but e.g. allow for reordering of packets? That wouldn’t be a problem but actually a feature, because it would allow me to continue processing some instruments even when packets for others have been lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would argue that you're looking at too low of a level. You should be looking at message queues like ZeroMQ or others  to build what's known as a service bus. ZeroMQ and most other message queue systems have client libraries for most popular languages and platforms. The connections are feather-light and scale highly. The message queues also support concepts like channels which allows clients to "subscribe" to topics that only interest them (eg particular stock tickers and the like). This capability known as Pub-Sub helps minimize network traffic over raw multicast in that messages are only delivered to those clients subscribing to a topic.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Really depends heavily on your throughput / latency requirements.
PGM can be made to work in a reliable (not guaranteed) manner but behaves terribly when you get anywhere near to the limitations of your network.
There are mechanisms for controlling multicast storms / slow subscribers etc... but I have never seen them work in practice.  The way the system fails and the tendency to impact many hosts (not just the one that may have started the issue) make it an absolute nightmare to manage in a support sense.
Even in low throughput environments, all it takes is one 'slow' network card to connect to the wrong MC channel and you've had it.
Most banks that have used multicast have either removed or are busy removing it and replacing it with better scaling TCP based systems.  The reason being pure and simply that it's unreliable and clunky.

I'd like to know how many subscribers you actually have for your data.  Are you absolutely sure you can't scale up ?  If your throughput requirements are high  you can look at hardware based systems like Solace, a namespace cleanup, multiple distribution points (like multiple smartsockets servers - I know they're rubbish, just an example) or something like that.

I'd avoid MC at all costs.  If you do end up using it, don't let it anywhere near desktops !